# can an env variable in a newman env json file be set while executing a collection run

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to do the following run newman within a jenkins pipeline. I am executing newman test using docker. However, my collection script has a few variables that need to be set that are dependent on the jenkins pipeline env. (i.e. since each jenkins build happens within a container, I need to find the IP address of that container and pass it on to the newman env JSON)...

for example in the following env config json:

```
{
  "id": "a14232bb-48d3-3494-7e6f-f4f34e6331a4",
  "name": "testEnv",
  "values": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "hostname",
      "value": "$IPADDRESS",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "port",
      "value": "$PORT",
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1504039485918,
  "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
  "_postman_exported_at": "2017-08-29T20:44:53.396Z",
  "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/5.1.3"
}
```

can the $PORT and $IPADDRESS be extracted from the shell env ?

1. is this something that can be done
2. Can we embed env command within the env file so that it gets interpretted when executed/used as part of the execution